# Adding integers inside list values within a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

Given:

```
a_dict = {3: [3, 7], 7: [6, 2], 2: [2, 1], 8: [-3, 9]}
```

I'm stuck on a problem where I have to return an updated dictionary that contains the sum of the elements inside the list values alongside its key. 
For example, the first key pair:

```
3: [3, 7]
```

is to be turned into this:

```
3: 10
```

Returned updated dictionary should look like this:

```
{3: 10, 7: 8, 2: 3, 8: 6}
```

I'm not sure if I should use the values method to isolate the values to get the sum of numbers from the list values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for key, val in a_dict.items():
    a_dict[key] = sum(val)
```

Comment: The trouble here is you are mutating the dict while iterating over it.  Consider iterating over a copy, or make a new dict.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict comprehension:

```
{k: sum(v) for k, v in a_dict.items()}
# {3: 10, 7: 8, 2: 3, 8: 6}
```